# PHP: How to Add New data json data to other nested json?

Tags: php, json

- List item

Here i am using php to get some results from Database with two different queries and i convert into JSON format, now i want to join the both json into one json.
I want to add new data into my old json, i tried with `array_merg()` to merge the two jsons but no success, i am new to,

json1:

```
{  
   "office_trip":[  
      {  
         "vnumber":"TN22BQ6226",
         "vname":"Mahindra Logan",
         "eid":"4",
         "name":"kumar",
         "mobile":"7449299394",
         "tid":"1",
         "vid":"TN22BQ6226",
         "emp_id":"4",
         "pick_place":"test1",
         "start_time":"11:45 am",
         "drop_place":"test11",
         "stop_time":"01:18 pm",
         "pickupkm":"10",
         "drops":"50",
         "type_of_trip":"Cash",
         "travelkm":"40",
         "tamt":"500",
         "dates":"2017-04-27",
         "expcal":"50",
         "exp1":"",
         "exp2":"",
         "exp3":"50",
         "exp4":"50",
         "exp5":"",
         "expamt":"50",
         "expdesc":"",
         "opeing_km":"0",
         "opeing_cash":"0",
         "closing_km":"40",
         "closing_cash":"0",
         "opeing_date":"2017-04-27",
         "opeing_time":"18:03:15",
         "closing_date":"2017-04-27",
         "closing_time":"18:04:05",
         "totkm":"40",
         "totamt":"500",
         "expenses":"50",
         "handover_amt":"400",
         "balance_amt":"50",
         "handover_to":"resr",
         "plstatus":"PROFIT",
         "entry_date":"2017-04-27"
      }
   ]
}
```

And i have another result from my database:

json2:

```
{"mycount":"1"}
```

i want to add this json2 into json1.after using `array_merge(json_decode($one, true),json_decode($two, true));` i get json1 separate and json1 separate.
how to merge with single json.

Expected output is,

```
{  
   "office_trip":[  
      {  
         "vnumber":"TN22BQ6226",
         "vname":"Mahindra Logan",
         "eid":"4",
         "name":"kumar",
         "mobile":"7449299394",
         "tid":"1",
         "vid":"TN22BQ6226",
         "emp_id":"4",
         "pick_place":"test1",
         "start_time":"11:45 am",
         "drop_place":"test11",
         "stop_time":"01:18 pm",
         "pickupkm":"10",
         "drops":"50",
         "type_of_trip":"Cash",
         "travelkm":"40",
         "tamt":"500",
         "dates":"2017-04-27",
         "expcal":"50",
         "exp1":"",
         "exp2":"",
         "exp3":"50",
         "exp4":"50",
         "exp5":"",
         "expamt":"50",
         "expdesc":"",
         "opeing_km":"0",
         "opeing_cash":"0",
         "closing_km":"40",
         "closing_cash":"0",
         "opeing_date":"2017-04-27",
         "opeing_time":"18:03:15",
         "closing_date":"2017-04-27",
         "closing_time":"18:04:05",
         "totkm":"40",
         "totamt":"500",
         "expenses":"50",
         "handover_amt":"400",
         "balance_amt":"50",
         "handover_to":"resr",
         "plstatus":"PROFIT",
         "entry_date":"2017-04-27",
         "mycount":"1"(HERE WE ADD)
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: sure wait a mint

Comment: i add my new json2 into last line as `"mycount":"1"` @SahilGulati

Comment: Hope my post will help you out....

Comment: wait i will try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784131)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string1='{  
   "office_trip":[  
      {  
         "vnumber":"TN22BQ6226",
         "vname":"Mahindra Logan",
         "eid":"4",
         "name":"kumar",
         "mobile":"7449299394",
         "tid":"1",
         "vid":"TN22BQ6226",
         "emp_id":"4",
         "pick_place":"test1",
         "start_time":"11:45 am",
         "drop_place":"test11",
         "stop_time":"01:18 pm",
         "pickupkm":"10",
         "drops":"50",
         "type_of_trip":"Cash",
         "travelkm":"40",
         "tamt":"500",
         "dates":"2017-04-27",
         "expcal":"50",
         "exp1":"",
         "exp2":"",
         "exp3":"50",
         "exp4":"50",
         "exp5":"",
         "expamt":"50",
         "expdesc":"",
         "opeing_km":"0",
         "opeing_cash":"0",
         "closing_km":"40",
         "closing_cash":"0",
         "opeing_date":"2017-04-27",
         "opeing_time":"18:03:15",
         "closing_date":"2017-04-27",
         "closing_time":"18:04:05",
         "totkm":"40",
         "totamt":"500",
         "expenses":"50",
         "handover_amt":"400",
         "balance_amt":"50",
         "handover_to":"resr",
         "plstatus":"PROFIT",
         "entry_date":"2017-04-27"
      }
   ]
}';
$json2='{"mycount":"1"}';
$array1=  json_decode($string1,true);
$array2=  json_decode($json2,true);

$array1["office_trip"][0]=array_merge($array1["office_trip"][0],$array2);
print_r(json_encode($array1,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```